# Test Page Speed Insights without waiting 28 days

Tags: pagespeed-insights

I test my website with [pagespeed](https://pagespeed.web.dev/). But to know exact result I should wait for 28 days. Is there are any way to test this without waiting?

I have tried to refresh and clear cache. I have tried to use different browsers. Also I have tried to find some answers in documentation but without expected result.

Comment: Just to clarify, the aggregation window covers 28 days, but it updates daily. So if you check again tomorrow, the stats should be slightly different, representing the ~most recent 28 days. That said, if you make a change to your website on Day 1, it will take the full 28 days to "flush" all older data out of the aggregation. As Tony suggests, you can measure it yourself to get data sooner.

Answer (score 1):

The extension solution proposed by Ihar will only help you test your own experiences.

You can gather your own real user metrics without the 28-day aggregation, and with a lot more details:

https://web.dev/articles/vitals-ga4

https://bigcommerce.websiteadvantage.com.au/tag-rocket/articles/core-web-vitals-ga4-bigquery-data-studio/